# how to convert landscape image to portrate image in IOS6?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

I am trying to take picture from camera in **landscape** mode and I want to show that image in **portrait** mode in **iOS6**. I can't rotate the image in portrait mode.

Answer (score 0):

You want to rotate, then what you are gonna to do with rotated image?
If you want to just show it in view, wrap it in `UIImageView`, rotate imageView and insert into view:

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage* image = [[info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] fixOrientation];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI * 90 / 180);
    [self.view addSubview:imageView];
}
```